# LINQ question ... need to get element with min value

Tags: c#, linq

Im new to linq so i still struggle ....

I have a collection of controls (each has a Location of type Point).
I need to remove the control with the lowest Y value (top control) from the collection.

An example would be most appreciated !

Comment: not with "SELECT", so you might want to change the title of your question.

Comment: Perhaps you mean lowest Y (top most control)! You should order the collection ascending by Y value and then pick the First value.

Comment: @chiccodoro thanx, didnt really know what to ask :)
@VinayC yeah, was too simple to think about it...

Comment: If you're talking about the `Controls` property in a Win Forms control, then you'll have to use `Enumerable.Cast<Control>` before you can use Linq methods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this:

```
collection.Remove(collection.OrderBy(c => c.Location.Y).First());
```

The ordering is quite expensive, so depending on your use-case you could also find the item with the lowest value and then remove it:

```
collection.Remove(collection.First(c => c.Y == collection.Min(c2 => c2.Y)));
```

This enumerates the list up to three times, generally this should still be faster than the OrderBy, but if performance is important to you then measure first.

Comment: @Simon, shouldn't it be c.Location.Y?

Comment: @Nathan Koop: It should be now, when I wrote it the question stated X :)

Comment: this works, but with .Last and not with .First.
If i use .First the control that gets removed has larger Y value.

Comment: Just to nitpick, it actually goes through the list 3 times, not twice.  The third time is in `collection.Remove`.  If we're really worried about performance here, the best way would be a simple `for` loop to find the lowest `Y` value *and* the index of the control with that value in one sweep through the list.  Then `collection.RemoveAt` wouldn't need to search through the list again.  If performance isn't an issue—and unless there were many, *many* controls, I don't imagine it would be—I would prefer your first example, as it's briefer, and IMO, easier to read.

Comment: @no9: I can't see how either of Simon's code samples would give you the control with the *largest* `Y` value.  `First` is indeed the correct function.

Comment: @P Daddy: Yup, thanks, was only thinking about the Linq parts. Corrected to three times.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to find the item and remove it, that's for sure. Remove is very clear, but while finding, you can use Aggregate method like this:

```
collection
   .Remove(collection
       .Aggregate((c1, c2) => c1.Point.Y < c2.Point.Y ? c1 : c2)
   )
);
```

Comment: This is a great answer.  It requires only one iteration of the collection to find the item, rather than two.  It could easily be used as a starting point for creating an extension method like `MinBy()` or `MaxBy()`.

Answer (score 4):

Ordering is more expensive. Just get the min value.

```
var lowest = (from c in collection
              where c.X == collection.Min(i => i.X)
              select c).FirstOrDefault();
collection.Remove(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that **LINQ** stands for Language INtegreated **Query**. That is, it's meant to be used as a tool for querying, not for *modifying* collections.

That said, you could find the control you need to remove using LINQ. Then simply remove it the normal way.

```
// Let's say controls is a ControlCollection
var enumerable = controls.Cast<Control>();
int minimumY = enumerable.Min(c => c.Location.Y);
Control topControl = enumerable.Where(c => c.Location.Y == minimumY);

controls.Remove(topControl);
```

Comment: LINQ is fine for modifying data. Structured Query Language is also for querying data, of course, and if you want to modify it you should use something else.

Comment: @amaca: LINQ is "fine for modifying data" in the sense that it *can* be used for this purpose. Side-effects cannot really be ensured against, except by the caller. But it really isn't *intended* for that purpose. To quote [Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx): "The purpose of an expression is to compute a value, not to cause a side effect."

Answer (score 0):

Below is an extension method that allows you to select min element as opposed to the min value. You can use like this:

`var lowest = collection.MinElement(x => x.Y);`

Then you can just remove the element with `collection.Remove(lowest)`.

```
public static T MinElement<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, int> selector) {
    if (source == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    }

    int minValue = 0;
    T minElement = default(T);
    bool hasValue = false;

    foreach (T s in source) {
        int x = selector(s);
        if (hasValue) {
            if (x < minValue) {
                minValue = x;
                minElement = s;
            }
        } else {
            minValue = x;
            minElement = s;
            hasValue = true;
        }
    }

    if (hasValue) {
        return minElement;
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException("MinElement: No elements in sequence.");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
collection.Remove( collection.Min( c => c.Y ));
```

Comment: `collection.Min( c => c.Y )` returns the minimum Y coordinate. As `collection.Remove` expects a control, this statement will result in a compile error.